# Setting readonly for all textboxes C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can anyone suggest a way to set readonly of all textboxes . I tried using a a recursive function but it will say that `System.Web.UI.Control` has no such definition for **ReadOnly**

```
    private void SetReadOnly<T>(Control parent, bool isReadOnly)
{
    foreach (Control ctrl in parent.Controls)
    {
        if (ctrl is T)
            ctrl.ReadOnly = isReadOnly;   // this line here wont work .
        SetReadOnly<T>(ctrl, isReadOnly);
    }
}
```

Any alternatives please !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that `T` can be *any* type and not all types have the property `ReadOnly`. Hence the compiler will choke.

You don't need to use generics to do this:

```
private void SetReadOnly(Control parent, bool readOnly)
{
  // Get all TextBoxes and set the value of the ReadOnly property.
  foreach (var tb in parent.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
    tb.ReadOnly = readOnly;

  // Recurse through all Controls
  foreach(Control c in parent.Controls)
    SetReadOnly(c, readOnly);
}
```

If you however would like to use generics you can do it like this:

```
private void SetReadOnly<T>(Control parent, bool readOnly) where T : TextBox
{
  // Get all TextBoxes and set the value of the ReadOnly property.
  foreach (var tb in parent.Controls.OfType<T>())
    tb.ReadOnly = readOnly;

  // Recurse through all Controls
  foreach(Control c in parent.Controls)
    SetReadOnly<T>(c, readOnly);
}
```

This will constrain the generic type to `TextBox` or *any class derived from it*. This assures that the `ReadOnly` property will always be there and the compiler knows this.

Answer (score 0):

You can set this on the client side using jQuery:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('input[type=text]').attr('readonly', true);
 });
```